# Unfortunately all my apps crash after updating to Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android-studio-2.2, crash

After updating Android Studio 2.2.3 the small apps I try to run keep crashing on instant run.I am testing the app on my Tecno P5 android version 4.2.2

I've been trying simple apps but to no success.With this one I am trying a simple splashscreen.
Here's the logcat:

```
> E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
>                                                                            org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line
> #17<vector> tag requires viewportHeight > 0
>                                                                                at
> android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:723)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:653)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:615)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:734)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:367)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:151)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
>                                                                                at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
>                                                                                at com.example.davy.splash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
>                                                                                at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
>                                                                                at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
>                                                                                at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
>                                                                                at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-23 23:27:05.179
> 4316-4316/com.example.davy.splash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
> main
>                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.davy.splash/com.example.davy.splash.MainActivity}:
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
> res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
>                                                                            at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
>                                                                            at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
>                                                                            at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                            at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
> res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
>                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1993)
>                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:673)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:151)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
>                                                                            at com.example.davy.splash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
>                                                                            at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
>                                                                            at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
>                                                                            at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
>                                                                            at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                            at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                         Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line
> #17: invalid drawable tag vector
>                                                                            at
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
>                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
>                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1990)
>                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:673) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:151) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525) 
>                                                                            at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74) 
>                                                                            at
> com.example.davy.splash.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122) 
>                                                                            at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081) 
>                                                                            at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
>                                                                            at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
>                                                                            at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

**MY Main acitvity:**

```
package com.example.davy.splash;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am experience the same thing until I change V2 to V1 signature. All apps crashed in Android 4.x devices (SDK API 19). Check if you are trying to generate signed APK by using Signature version 2 or version 1. APK Signature Scheme v2 targetting Android 7.0 (API level 24). Use version 1 if you are targeting Android 4.x [V1 Signature for earlier Android 4-6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zngev.png)